# Which Java state machine framework has a functional visual eclipse-3.7 editor?

Tags: java, frameworks, eclipse-plugin, code-generation, fsm

there appear to be some Java FSM frameworks with editors like Unimod and Apache SCXML but the former has problems with eclipse-3.7, and the latter isn't even released. As a second possibility I would use a standalone visual editor---but this question is about whether there is such a framework with fitting editor plugin that is reportedly used by you, if you're an eclipse-3.7 user. It would be applied in a desktop GUI application setting.

So, which Java state machine framework has a functional visual eclipse-3.7 editor?

Comment: Q: What exactly have you tried?  What happened?  Q: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: The question is in the subject line. But I'll append it at the bottom to emphasize it.

Comment: A: I tried Unimod but I couldn't find out how to launch the plugin. It appears from the bug tracker that it won't work with newer eclipse versions.

Comment: Cool - thanx for the clarification.  Unimod appears to be very old ... and rather unsupported.  Have you tried Eclipse GMF?  http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/gmf

Comment: No. It doesn't appear to be what I'm looking for: no FSM framework, no editor for state machines.

Comment: It looks as if GMF is a library to build such an editor. But I'm looking for a working implementation.

Comment: Please look at [this GMF tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Graphical_Modeling_Framework/Tutorial#Get_started).  One other option might be: [scxmlgui](http://code.google.com/p/scxmlgui/).